# Jquery doesn't work with .this

Tags: jquery

As I've said: Jquery doesn't work .this selection, what am I doing wrong? altho it works with other parametres. Here's code of mt mini gallery that's supposed to enlarge selected image and move down non-selected (works on single elements tho)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content img").click(function () {
        $("#blackb").slideDown("slow");
        $("img", this).animate({
            right: "20%"
        });
        $("img", this).animate({
            top: "20%"
        });
        $("img", this).animate({
            width: 802,
            height: 584
        }, "slow");
        $("#content img").not(this).animate({
            top: "80%"
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

HTML part:

```
<div id="content">

    <img id="second" src="model.jpg" alt="model" />
    <img id="third" src="model.jpg" alt="model" />
    <img id="fourth" src="model.jpg" alt="model" />
    <img id="first" src="model.jpg" alt="model" />
    </div>
<div id="blackb"></div>
```

CSS part:

```
#content img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    display: none;
    width: 160px;
    height: 116px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    z-index: 10;
}
#blackb{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 888px;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the HTML and CSS related to the selectors... #content img, #blackb, #img?

Comment: Just redited and they r there, im not using general img settings (#img).
black b is just the background of gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('img', this)` is looking for an image node in the context of your image node that was clicked.

Since an image can't be a child of an image, it doesn't make any sense.

You can either select with `$(this)`, or bind the click to something higher up and continue to use `this` as the context.

Comment: Based on your edit, your selectors just need to be `$(this)`. The last selector is fine.

Comment: I think, in this situation, `$(this)` is the solution you're looking for.